# Auto-increment data validation in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have basically zero Google Sheets experience. I have followed an infoinspired document with a section titled "How to Create a Multi-Row Dynamic Dependent Drop Down List in Google Sheets [Advanced]" to create three different lists of attributes from which to select based upon the attribute selected in the previous column of the same row.

The biggest problem is that it appears Google doesn't allow dragging down the column to increment the data validation. My data validation references a separate sheet list from a range currently using "Traits!B1:J1."

Is there a script that can be used by simply dragging so that the range will increment for each row thus resulting in:
B1:J1, 
B2:J2, 
B3:J3, 
B4:J4, 
etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's thanks to a alternate forum response by James/mreighties pointing me to a couple videos by Learn Google Spreadsheets, which provided EXACTLY what I needed. The essential script giving the solutions appears here:

```
    function onEdit(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("data")
  
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){
  
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();

      var makes = datass.getRange(1, 1, 1, datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
      var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;
      
        if(makeIndex != 0) {
  
      var validationRange = datass.getRange(3, makeIndex, datass.getLastRow());
      var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
  
  }
  
}
}
```

With just a bit of massaging, I got this to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you can just drag this down without script:

```
="B"&ROW(B1)&":J"&ROW(J1)
```